# Installation of PythonNet in Visual Studio 2019 throw System.TypeInitializationException , DllNotFoundException

Tags: python, c#, .net, visual-studio, python.net

Currently trying out pythonNet to see how easy it is to call python code from csharp, I would have gone for ironpython but I have read that you can't choose a 3.x python version, which can be limiting.

I first get a fresh installation of python3.8

I have cloned pythonNet from [GitHub](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet), then used `pip install .` from the directory where I cloned it to generate Python.Runtime.dll in
"C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pythonnet\runtime".

I then reference this dll in my VS project, and add the code as given in the PythonNet demo:

```
Runtime.PythonDLL = @"C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python38.dll";
using (Py.GIL())
{
    dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
    Console.WriteLine(np.cos(np.pi * 2));

    dynamic sin = np.sin;
    Console.WriteLine(sin(5));

    double c = (double)(np.cos(5) + sin(5));
    Console.WriteLine(c);

    dynamic a = np.array(new List<float> { 1, 2, 3 });
    Console.WriteLine(a.dtype);

    dynamic b = np.array(new List<float> { 6, 5, 4 }, dtype: np.int32);
    Console.WriteLine(b.dtype);

    Console.WriteLine(a * b);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

But I immediately get:

> System.TypeInitializationException:An exception was thrown by the type initializer for 'Delegates'.

With two inner exceptions:

> DllNotFoundException: Could not load C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python38.dll.

> Win32Exception: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

I can't find what step of the installations I'm missing, has anyone had this exception before?

Here is the stack trace:

```
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\dev\Source\Repos\compcat\ERSF.AI.CompCatV2\bin\Debug\ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\common7\ide\PrivateAssemblies\Runtime\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.Desktop.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.App..ctor'
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.App.InitializeComponent'
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_fr_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\dev\Source\Repos\compcat\ERSF.AI.CompCatV2\bin\Debug\Python.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\netstandard\v4.0_2.0.0.0__cc7b13ffcd2ddd51\netstandard.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero2\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_fr_31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Reflection.Emit\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Reflection.Emit.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe): Loaded '__CodeGenerator_Assembly'. 
'ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ERSF.AI.CompCatV2.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in Python.Runtime.dll
An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Python.Runtime.dll but was not handled in user code
Une exception a été levée par l'initialiseur de type pour 'Delegates'.
```

Edit:
Alright, I found out that you need to actually specify the architecture x64 in build properties, and things seems to have fixed themselves

Comment: I'm having similar issues... Are you talking about the build properties in VS? I specified it as x64, and I'm still getting the DllNotFoundException.

Comment: @levente.nas Did you find a solution? I have the same problem, setting to x64 build did not fix things. Even if I specify just the x64 dll in the path (to eliminate any 32 bit issue presumably) and set python.runtime I still get this error!