# Error trying to use python.net integration

Tags: python, c#, .net, python.net

Trying to use python from .net using python.net I installed latest pythonnet nuget package. I have python 3.11 installed. Python.Runtime version is 3.0.1 and .NET framework 4.8 building with AnyCPU. There is some tweak I am missing I think. When I do:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pathToPython = @"C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\python311";
        string path = pathToPython + ";" +
                      Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", pathToPython, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        var lib = new[]
                  {
            @"C:\code\python scripts",
            @"C:\code\python scripts\.venv",
            @"C:\code\python scripts\Lib",
            @"C:\code\python scripts\Lib\site-packages",
        };

        string paths = string.Join(";", lib);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", paths, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        Runtime.PythonDLL = @"C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python311.dll";



        using (Py.GIL())
        { ..some python call
```

I get this error:
DllNotFoundException: Could not load C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python311.dll.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Edit-Full error message:

```
System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'Delegates' threw an exception.
  Source=Python.Runtime
  StackTrace:
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Delegates.get_PyGILState_Ensure()
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.PyGILState_Ensure()
   at Python.Runtime.Py.GIL()
   at PythonNetIntegration.Interop.Main(String[] args) in C:\code\PythonNetIntegration\Interop.cs:line 35

Inner Exception 1:
DllNotFoundException: Could not load C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python311.dll.

Inner Exception 2:
Win32Exception: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: Please, provide the full error message.

Comment: Hey @LOST I updated question with full error message. I can confirm that "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python311.dll" definitely exists.

Comment: Try to search for other error messages. You will find your answers.

Comment: @LOST Thanks! I looked and I have posted all the exceptions I am currently getting already above. Its a bit frustrating, because once it gets going its a thing of beauty! I had it working with a prior version months ago, and back then there was no Runtime.Python setting requirement. Its something small perhaps, but I don't seem to be able to figure it out :(

Comment: I did explore the "Win32Exception: %1 is not a valid Win32 application" error. Setting the build to x64 as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71078532/installation-of-pythonnet-in-visual-studio-2019-throw-system-typeinitializatione
did not solve my problem. Doing so threw a "System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory" error.

Comment: The access violation sounds like a mistake somewhere else in the code, and the library might be actually working.